# How to open and edit a CSV file with 2 different programs?

Tags: python, vba, database, csv

I am building a bot with python, and this bot saves data into CSV file, so every time the python open the file, edit, save.

The thing is - I am connected to that CSV using VBA (through SQL), and every X seconds the VBA reads the CSV and calculates some things from that CSV file.

The problem comes when there is this moment where the python is writing to that CSV and the VBA wants to read from that CSV **on the same time** or vice versa, if the VBA reads from the csv and then python is crashing due to permission error.

What are the solution for those kind of things? that more than 1 program needs to access on the same time the CSV file?

Comment: Wait a _random_ count of seconds, then try again.

Comment: Your python programme could create an extra file like csv_file.pyt when the programme access the file to indicate the file is locked. At the end your Python programme deletes the lock file. The VBA programme could do the same.

Comment: @Storax what do you man? can i have an example?

Comment: An option could be to create a lock-file. The first application writing to the file creates the lock-file. If a lock-file is present, other applications will wait until it is removed before writing to the file. Does this comment make it clearer.

Comment: Yes - I suppose it's a good idea, thank you.